# merge columns of a csv file in python with variable entries in every row in?

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have 2 csv files

One has traceroutes to different IP addresses(The last entry here is the target IP) also (their are variable number of entries in every row as different routes need different no. of hops)

other has a list of targets and their real world positional coordinates

some targets in first file dont have an entry in the 2nd and vice versa

How do I get the real world cordinates into the 1st csv file with matching target IPs?
the 2 files are like these

```
hop1,hop2,hop3,hop4,target1
hop1,hop2,hop3,hop4,hop5,hop6,target2

target99,position
```

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be in Python? You can do this with a single command in the GNU/Linux commandline: `join` (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#join-invocation)

Comment: Just checked the docs for 'join'- I don't think it can operate on a file with a variable number of fields per line, like the one in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

ip_file = open("ipfile.csv")
position_file = open("positionfile.csv")
output = open("output.csv", "wt")

ips = {}    

# create a CSV reader for the proper csv file with locations:
reader = csv.reader(position_file)
for line in reader:
    ips[line[0]] = line[1]


#now you have the IP + location association

for line in ip_file.readlines():
    ip = line.split(",")[-1].strip()
    output.write(line.strip() + ", " + (ips[ip] if ip in ips else "location unknown") + "\n" )

output.close()
```

Comment: ips[line[0]] = line[1]
NameError: name 'ips' is not defined

Comment: Sorry - fixed now. I had cut it away by mistake.

Comment: thanks. how do I skip the location unknown entry entirely from output?

Comment: just chnage the inline `if ip`  statement to control the execution of the output.write line